# Get value of a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print out the only value of the class I click on.

I've tried some stuff but I can't get it right the way I want to

Here is a small example what I mean

```
var myVal = $(".test") .getAttribute('value');
$( ".test" ).click(function() {
alert(myVal)
});
```

[codepen Example](http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/KpjRGv)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the value of the class'? Do you want to print the content of the element?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pxsz4kvk/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use like this :

```
//var myVal = $(".test").getAttribute('value');
$( ".test" ).click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('value'))
});
```

For better implementation, use `data` attribute for user defined attribute like so :

```
<div class="test" value="1" data-value="1">Value 1</div>
<div class="test" value="2" data-value="2">Value 2</div>
<div class="test" value="3" data-value="3">Value 3</div>
<div class="test" value="4" data-value="4">Value 4</div>
<div class="test" value="5" data-value="5">Value 5</div>
```

Then js is :

```
$(".test").click(function () {
  var dataValue = $(this).data('value');
  alert(dataValue);    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/mvcf2brc/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("your_element").on('click',function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   alert(myClass);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use AngularJs, it is better than jquery because it works better with bindings. Here is a small example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WDCgs0rFfyqXhmylcF6D?p=preview

```
    <body ng-app="">
  <p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, 'has-error': error}">Map Syntax Example</p>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="deleted">
   deleted (apply "strike" class)
</label><br>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".test").click(function () {
           alert($(this).attr('value'));
     });
 });
```